# vim: taglist fails to generate tags

Tags: vim, ctags, vim-plugin, taglist

When trying to run taglist (`:TlistToggle`) on a .py file I get the error:

```
Taglist: Failed to generate tags for /Users/...py
ctags: illegal option -- -^@usage: ctags [-BFatuwvx] [-f tagsfile] file ...^@
```

I've downloaded the latest taglist and ctags plugins, and ran `:let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd = '"/usr/local/bin/ctags"'` within vim (I'm on OS X, running vim in the terminal).

Any thoughts to why I get the above error?

Comment: Did you set the shell variable `CTAGSFLAGS` to anything or does `echo $CTAGSFLAGS` output nothing?

Comment: You're quite right.. that outputs nothing!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taglist only supports "exuberant ctags tool", not "GNU ctags or the Unix ctags", see the [FAQ](http://vim-taglist.sourceforge.net/faq.html).

I use [tagbar](http://majutsushi.github.com/tagbar/) instead of it.

Comment: special thanks for `tagbar` suggestion, I didn't know about it, seems to be much better taglist!

Comment: Many thanks for this! Installed it and it works straight away.

Answer (score 1):

You need "exuberant ctags tool" and you can follow following steps to build your own and install.

1. download crags from http://ctags.sourceforge.net
2. Extract ctags to a folder ( ex e-ctags )
3. Goto that folder ( cd e-crags )
4. ./configure
5. ./make

Once you have the binary you can move it to your bin folder as:

sudo mv ctags /usr/bin/ctags-exuberant

and use ctags-exuberant instead of ctags.

Comment: I think you need to use `make` instead of `./make`. To use ctags-exuberant you will need to add this line to your .vimrc: 
`let Tlist_Ctags_Cmd='/usr/bin/ctags-exuberant'`